# HAProxy running inside Docker container always logging same client IP

Tags: docker, proxy, frontend, ip-address, haproxy

I have a docker container running haproxy inside, and while it seems to work well, I'm running into a problem where the client IP that reaches the frontend, and shows up on the haproxy logs, is always the same, just with a different port. This IP seems to be the same as the IPV4 IPAM Gateway of the network where the container is running inside (192.168.xx.xx).

The problem with this is that since every request that reaches the proxy has the same client IP, no matter the machine or network where it came from, it's easy for someone with bad intentions to trigger the security restrictions, which bans said IP and no request gets through until the proxy is reset, because every request seems to be coming from the same banned IP.

This is my current haproxy config: (I tried to reduce it to the bare minimum, without the restrictions rules, timeouts, etc, for ease of understanding. I'm testing with this setup and the problem is still present)

```
global
    log stdout format raw local0 info

defaults
    mode http
    log global
    option httplog
    option forwardfor

frontend fe
    bind :80

    default_backend be

backend be
    server foo_server $foo_server_IP_and_Port

backend be_abuse_table
    stick-table type ip size 1m expire 15m store conn_rate(3s),conn_cur,gpc0,http_req_rate(15s),http_err_rate(20s)
```

I have tried setting and adding headers, I've also tried to put the container running in the host network, but the problem is that the request does not reach the backend server because it's in a different network, furthermore, I would like to keep the container in the network where it's at, alongside the other containers.

Also, does the backend server configuration influence in any way this problem I'm having? My understanding is that since the problem is already present when reaching the frontend, the backend configuration doesn't matter for this problem.

Any suggestions? This has been driving me crazy for 2 days now. Thank you so much!

Comment: need to run it host mode

Comment: @DefSoudani Do you mean putting the container running on the host network? I tried that and the requests don't even reach the proxy. Furthermore, I'm not sure they would reach the backend server running on the bridge network

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was I was using docker rootless mode. You can either use normal docker or you can use rootless and install the slirpn4netns package and change the port forwarder, following these steps (the section about changing the port forwarder): https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started/docker/#changing-the-port-forwarder